# Async networking racecondition

Tags: multithreading, networking, asynchronous, synchronization, race-condition

I am writing a client for a networked application and I would like to seperate receiving and processing the messages to different threads.

This is my solution at the moment:

```
Mutex mutex;
Queue queue;

recv()
{
    while(true)
    {
        messages = receive_some_messages();

        mutex.lock();
        queue.add(messages);
        mutex.unlock();

        process.notify();
    }
}

proc()
{
    while(true)
    {
        block_until_notify();
        Queue to_process;

        mutex.lock();
        to_process.add( queue.take_all() );
        mutex.unlock();

        foreach(message in to_process)
        {
            process_message(message);
        }

    }
}
```

This has a race condition however:

1. *recv* receives a lot of messages and puts them in queue.
2. *recv* notifices *proc*.
3. *proc* takes all messages from queue and starts working
4. *recv* receives some more messages and puts them in queue
5. *recv* notifies *proc*, but as *proc* is still working this does nothing.
6. *proc* completes its iteration.
7. *proc* blocks - **there are still unprocessed messages in queue**

I can think of several methods of fixing it, however none are favorable.

### Solution 1

I could adapt sync to keep the lock on the mutex during the processing:

```
proc()
{
    while(true)
    {
        block_until_notify();
        Queue to_process;

        mutex.lock();
        to_process.add( queue.take_all() );

        foreach(message in to_process)
        {
            process_message(message);
        }
        mutex.unlock(); 
    }
}
```

But this would mean the threads run exclusively: either *recv* or *proc* is active, but not both.

### Solution 2

I could remove the block and notify.

```
recv()
{
    while(true)
    {
        messages = receive_messages();

        mutex.lock();
        queue.add(messages);
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}

proc()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Queue to_process;

        mutex.lock();
        to_process.add( queue.take_all() );
        mutex.unlock();

        foreach(message in to_process)
        {
            process_message(message);
        }

    }
}
```

But this means that the *proc* will run in a busy-wait loop, only blocking when *recv* is adding messages to queue.

### The question

I would like a solution where *proc* and *recv* do not run exclusively and without busy-waiting.
Does anybody have any idea on what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get by if the consumer checks for an empty queue after the queue is drained.

```
proc()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Queue to_process;

        mutex.lock();

        if (queue.empty()) {
           mutex.unlock();
           block_until_notify();
           mutex.lock();
        }

        to_process.add( queue.take_all() );

        mutex.unlock();

        foreach(message in to_process)
        {
            process_message(message);
        }

    }
}
```

I believe that this fixes the race condition you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also believe this will fix the race condition.

Comment: @Damacustas: It's actually the same solution suggested in the first paragraph of the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `block_until_notify()` function is probably a condition variable. The way to do this is to change that function so that you lock the mutex, check that the queue is empty, then wait for notification. If the queue is not empty then you proceed with processing it. After processing the queue you return to the block_until_notify function and repeat the process, again checking if the queue is empty before blocking.

If you aren't using a condition variable of some kind then I'd suggest using a semaphore. On a Windows system you'd call `ReleaseSemaphore` every time messages were added to the queue. The receiver would call `WaitForSingleObject` on the semaphore handle. That would be done in a loop and the loop would continue to repeat, even if the queue is empty, until the wait blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the semaphore.